# Export of an empty xlsx to pdf with libreoffice results in a Write Error

Tags: libreoffice

Within Libreoffice (tested with 4.1.x), I can open an empty (no content) xlsx file.
Export as PDF though results in a "Write Error. The file could not be written.".
In ".config/libreoffice/4/user/temp/document_io_logring.txt", I see:

```
...
/home/cloph/source/libo-core/sfx2/source/doc/objstor.cxx:1546: Storing in alien format.
/home/cloph/source/libo-core/sfx2/source/doc/sfxbasemodel.cxx:3088: Storing has failed, no error is set!
/home/cloph/source/libo-core/sfx2/source/doc/sfxbasemodel.cxx:3128: Storing failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42166. It happens when you manually export an empty xls or when using the API.